# WebSocket connectivity issues

Tags: javascript, java, firefox, websocket, connectivity

I have one websocket server running in java application written using https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket and trying to connect to it
from browser. The browser is sending request to connect every second till the websocket server initializes. Chrome connects blazingly fast as soon the websocket is initialized. Firefox takes atleast 10-15 seconds to connect. Is there any way firefox to connect as chrome connects. I have checked the headers in both browser "keep-alive" header is sent in firefox and chrome doesnot send. Will it be affecting the connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. It was becuase i was using the old version which was created in 2013. The spec and implementation changed a lot. Thanks @Nitish Dhapodkar i used that website to check connectivity.

Comment: Then if you can, please upvote Nitish's answer as it helped you. Furthermore, please accept your answer to mark this question as closed

Answer (score 1):

First test with this..
http://demos.kaazing.com/echo/
so that you will be able to know which side is the problem.